# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive (After file upload completed)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In Asp.Net MVC 5
I use this code in a class to upload my file in FTP Server.

```
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpURL);
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
        ftpRequest.Timeout = -1;
        Stream requestStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        long fileSize = 0;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[buferSize];
        int bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buferSize);
        fileSize += bytesRead;
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buferSize);
            fileSize += bytesRead;
        }
        requestStream.Close();

        return fileSize;
```

and I have this config in web.config because files are too big:

```
<location path="Programs/Upload">
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="86400" maxRequestLength="2097152" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

When I try to upload small files (in release mode with debug = 'false') everything work well. but when file size become big I face with this error (after file completely uploaded):

```
**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive**
```

The file is completely uploaded and is available in FTP Server!